# Inserting variable stored data into SQLite3 - Python 3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have been reading information on how to insert data into a database using data stored in a variable.  I have not been able to get my data to load to my database and I am not sure why.

The program is written to check for an existing DB and if it does not exist than it creates it along with the tables and columns required, that all works fine.

I have tried to follow the methods from the various tutorials I have been reading but I must be missing something or doing something incorrectly.

The database and table creates properly (I did not include that part of the code, it is executed at the start of the program).  Further into my program code I am using the following routine to enter the user input data by clicking of the "Submit" button

Button routine:

```
submit = Button(
    window3, 
    font=('arial',12,'bold'), text='Submit', 
    width=12, height=1, bg='aliceblue', 
    fg='steel blue', command = Submit
)
```

My Submit Routine:

```
def Submit():
    connect = sqlite3.connect('SSRB.db')
    connect.execute('''
    INSERT INTO ssrb (date, time_in, time_out, company, plate, province, driver, pass1,
     pass2, pass3, deliver, contact, entry_by, pi_yes, pi_no, pi_violations, pi_done_by,
     vi_yes, vi_no, vi_violations, vi_done_by)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,
     %s), (Date, TimeIn, TimeOut, Company, Plate, Province, Driver, Pass1, Pass2, Pass3,
     Delivery, Contact, EntryBy, PIYES, PINO, PIFound, PIDoneBy, VIYES, VINO,
    VIFound, VIDoneBy)
    ''')
    connect.commit()
    connect.close()
```

The columns in the table are listed after the INSERT, the %s is placed after the VALUES and the variables holding the user input is listed last.

I am not seeing where I am going wrong... can someone please point out what I am doing incorrectly?

Much thanks as always.

Comment: I guess that `Date, TimeIn, TimeOut` and so on are variables in Python? If so the variable names can't be enclosed in the string and send to Sqlite as they are

Comment: You're hardcoding what looks like variable names into the string, so when you do `"INSERT INTO... (Date)"` you're inserting the string `"Date"`, not the value of your `Date` variable. I think your `'''` have *gone too far* **:-)**

Comment: Moreover, use `?` as parameter substitution for Sqlite instead of `%s`

Comment: @Michael Butscher the variables names are as you thought... such as "Date, TimeIn, TimeOut".
I have then set as StringVar() in this fashion:
Date=StringVar() - converting any input through the textbox to a StringVar().
Should I or would it be better if I use something like Date = Date instead?
I did not think to try that.

Answer (score 0):

See the **execute** function description in the [sqlite documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects).

Statement variables should be in a second argument to **execute(...)**, a tuple containing all the parameters.

Replace the `%s` in the statement string with `?` as per the documentation specifications, for sanity.

You need code like this:

```
def Submit():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('SSRB.db')
    conn.execute('''
    INSERT INTO ssrb (date, time_in, time_out, company, plate, province, driver, pass1, 
    pass2, pass3, deliver, contact, entry_by, pi_yes, pi_no,  pi_violations, pi_done_by, 
    vi_yes, vi_no, vi_violations, vi_done_by)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', 
    (Date, TimeIn, TimeOut, Company, Plate, Province, Driver, Pass1, Pass2, Pass3, 
    Delivery, Contact, EntryBy, PIYES, PINO, PIFound, PIDoneBy, VIYES, VINO, VIFound, 
    VIDoneBy))
    connect.commit()
    connect.close()
```

*Addendum 1*: Variables in the parameters tuple should be primitives (integers, floats etc).

Comment: I have tried that exactly a number of time but it has not been working.
I just ran it again and I am getting the following error message:
  File "C:\Users\Home\Documents\Thonny Workshop\SSRB\New SSRB-4.py", line 63, in Submit
    Province, Driver, Pass1, Pass2, Pass3, Delivery, Contact, EntryBy, PIYES, PINO, PIFound, PIDoneBy, VIYES, VINO, VIFound, VIDoneBy))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Could you shed some light on the error?

Comment: Saw other comments regarding `Date.get()`. Sqlite only accepts "primitives" for parameter values - integers, floats, strings, booleans. An *unsupported type* error means a value is something else, which sqlite cannot parse.

Comment: I declared the variables as follows:
date = Entry(window3, font=('arial',12), textvariable= date, bg = 'aliceblue',bd=2, insertwidth=2)

Then I declared the textvariable as:
date=StringVar()

Then this variable was attempted to be used in the INSERT string for the db.

However it did not work out the way it should have and I am a bit confused why it was such a chore. (still very new to coding python)

Comment: Sqlite itself can only interpret integers, floats, strings, booleans and strings / integers representing timestamps. The sqlite3 module tries to map supplied variables to these types, but it needs to know how to do this. It would not know how to map an `Entry` object, in general. Either there is a way to *register* the Entry class, so it knows how to map such objects, or you convert the Entry instance to a value already recognised ( hence, the `Date.get()` invokation ).

Comment: I am following what you have said, or I believe I do however looking at my above comment showing my flow does it not then take what is held in the entry box named "date=Entry(..."  then become a declared or known string by stating "date=StringVar()" whereby the value of the entry would be then assigned to the StringVar() "date" using the entry in textvariable=date?

Comment: At this point I recommend editing your question, and explain what each parameter is (or what it represents).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
connect.execute('''
INSERT INTO ssrb (date, time_in, time_out, company, plate, province, driver, pass1,
 pass2, pass3, deliver, contact, entry_by, pi_yes, pi_no, pi_violations, pi_done_by,
 vi_yes, vi_no, vi_violations, vi_done_by)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,
 %s), (Date, TimeIn, TimeOut, Company, Plate, Province, Driver, Pass1, Pass2, Pass3,
 Delivery, Contact, EntryBy, PIYES, PINO, PIFound, PIDoneBy, VIYES, VINO,
VIFound, VIDoneBy)
''')
```

use

```
connect.execute('''
INSERT INTO ssrb (date, time_in, time_out, company, plate, province, driver, pass1,
 pass2, pass3, deliver, contact, entry_by, pi_yes, pi_no, pi_violations, pi_done_by,
 vi_yes, vi_no, vi_violations, vi_done_by)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
 ?)''', (Date, TimeIn, TimeOut, Company, Plate, Province, Driver, Pass1, Pass2, Pass3,
 Delivery, Contact, EntryBy, PIYES, PINO, PIFound, PIDoneBy, VIYES, VINO,
VIFound, VIDoneBy)
)
```

They are 2 differences:

1. Symbol `?` instead of `%s` as it is not a Python's syntax for the string's `.format()` method (or older `%` notation) but the *DB-API’s parameter substitution symbol*.
2. Ending `'''` are moved up - where the `INSERT INTO` (parametrized) statement *really* ends.
   (The substitution itself is performed by the `.execute()` method by its *2<sup>nd</sup> parameter* - a tuple provided by you.)

Comment: I appreciate the insight and I had tried it the way you have posted before asking here using both the ? instead of the %s and I also moved up the ' ' ' to the end of the ? statement.
I have just modified it again and give it a try but it is still not inserting the data to the db.

I have checked the table column names and the variable names over and over again to make sure there are no errors or mismatches and they are all proper.

Could there be something else that is wrong?

Comment: If your field names are in the same order as in your table try omit them completely, i. e. use `INSERT INTO ssrb VALUES (?, ?, ...)`.

Comment: #MarianD I have given this a try and it does not write to the data either.

I am wondering if it might be how I have the variables collecting the input data, but I don't think it should mater as long as the variable is not flushed prior to inserting to the DB.

Each variable is collecting the user input in separate def routines, would this cause this problem of not writing?

I am using labels with frames to run in the main window3. When the program runs everything appears properly.
Is there a way to have the variable display what it contains so I can check to see if the data is there?

Comment: There may be problem with the scope of variables - the variable in the inner scope (your function definition) with the same name is *different* (= newly created) from variable in the outer scope *if you try changing its value (e.g. by assign to it)*. Try perform your commands from Python interpreter with (in advance) manually assigning values to your variables.

Comment: @MarionD I am not sure I follow you on your comment regarding the scope of the variables. I'm still quite new to python programming.
Here is what I've done.
Defined a routine for a user to enter the data into the entry box as follows:
date = Entry(window3, font=('arial',12), textvariable= Date, bg = 'aliceblue',bd=2, insertwidth=2)

I then have the textvariable declared as Date=StringVar()

I then have the INSERT INTO DB.

This should work as I understand it but the variable Date=StringVar() doesn't seem to hold the data from the entry box for it to load to the DB.

Comment: Did you try what I recommended in my previous comment? - Example about an issue with scopes: `a = 7; def get_a(): a = 5` Then after executing the command `a = get_a()` the value of the variable `a` will be still `7`, i. e. unchanged.

Comment: @MarionD I did that to verify the data in the variable is correct and it does show that what ever is entered into the text box is being stored in the variable. The issue now is to find out why it is not inserting into the tables in the data base.
I have looked up the error it give and there is a lot of different threads on why this occurs but nothing that makes sense in my situation yet.
I am still experimenting with various ways to try to fix the problem but any suggestions from the members here are always welcome to help me learn.
This insert issue has to be something simple!

Comment: @MarionD I have managed to correct the problem by experimenting with variations of the insert command lines.  In the line that states the VALUES and the variables:  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', (date, timeIn, timeOut)...) I had to make the change to it to state the following:  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', (date.get(), (timeIn.get()), (timeOut.get())...)

I have no understanding of why I had to do it this way but it is the only way I managed to get it to insert the data into the db.

Comment: It's exactly what I said - you assigned `date.get()` etc. to *local* variables of functions while *outer* variables (which you used in your `.execute()˛` method) were unmodified. Now you used them directly so there is not such problem. - Please consider accept my answer (click on the check mark) and / or upvote my answer if it was useful for you.